# How to store large Amount of data like arrays and dictionaries in iOS

Tags: ios, save, large-data

Up to now I used NSUserDefaults to store some data.But now I have arouund 20 categories each contain around 1000 dictionary values.

What is the better place to store them

Is NSUserDefaults?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not for data.

Comment: @rmaddy Im storing some arrays in NSUserDefaults, is this wrong

Comment: Probably. `NSUserDefaults` should only be for little bits of info such as user preferences. Data should be stored elsewhere.

Comment: May be, but i used it one of my app and didn't get any issues. Any way thanks for info..

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to change the data sometime when the app is running, try with CoreData or sqlite.
I you just save data to file at the end, and load at beginning, try with .plist.

try [RealM](https://realm.io) --> much more faster combined with coreData and sqlite , optimize the code and save the time also

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is better option for the storing data.

Core Data is not a Database. It is object persistence Storage. You can easily manage your data (CRUD operations).

For example, you are about to `categories`.

So you can `create One Model named Category`.

And there you can define One `String like categoryType`. And another is `Dictionary type that have name categoryDetail`.

Then you can store it and retrieve, update and delete also.

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/

Comment: Could u plz provide me some tutorials which will be easy to understand for the beginner

Comment: Thanks, I will go through them